# CKSubscription with complex predicate

Tags: ios, cloudkit, cksubscription

I am trying to use `CKSubscription` this way:

```
NSArray *events = @[@1,@2,@3];
NSInteger myValue = 100;

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"(value > %@) AND (prev_value < %@) AND (event_type IN %@)",
    @(myValue), @(myValue), events];

CKSubscription *sub = [[CKSubscription alloc] initWithRecordType:@"TableName"
    predicate:predicate options:(CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordCreation)];

[db saveSubscription:sub completionHandler:^(CKSubscription *s, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"Success!");
}];
```

This getting me error:

```
Error: Error saving record subscription with id 781FB482-C9C9-4DA5-8022-CFDB8006223A to server:
invalid attempt to set value type NUMBER_INT64 for field 'binding_0' for type
'_sub_trigger_sub_220b17724b5262b0590a3c9d66be9826', defined to be: INT64_LIST
```

This looks like valid `NSPredicate` can not be properly stored in CloudKit as part of `CKSubscription` object. It that real Apple bug or mine?

P.S. I have tried a lot of different combinations by removing different parts of predicate condition. Looks like the only condition for `event_type` works fine, but when I am mixing 3 conditions with `AND` - this causes a problem.

P.P.S. I am using `Xcode 6 beta 6` on `OSX 10.10 DP6` and `iOS8 beta 5` on iPhone 5S

**UPDATE:**

Subscriptions with one of the following predicates works fine:

```
NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"(value > %@) AND (prev_value < %@)", @(myValue), @(myValue)];

NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"(event_type IN %@)", events];
```

But saving subscription with common predicate fails:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"(value > %@) AND (prev_value < %@) AND (event_type IN %@)",
    @(myValue), @(myValue), events];
```

Looks like real Apple CloudKit bug. Just opened issue at bugreport.apple.com #18105879

**UPDATE 2:**

Thanks to @purrrminator - here are two radars with problem with receiving CloudKit push notifications:

http://openradar.appspot.com/18807663

http://openradar.appspot.com/18798061

I found workaround for saving `CKSubscription` properly via presenting `IN` condition with a lot of equality comparers. But really I got no push notifications from CLoudKit...

Comment: All these fields: `value`, `prev_value` and `event_type` are `Int64`.

Comment: Are these actual failing values in myValue & events?

Comment: @BenLachman actual myValue is 1022, and events are @[@1,@2,@3].

Comment: I have problem too creating compound predicate with more conditions, it seems CloudKit stores it inconsistently, you can try fetch subscriptions and print out all subpredicate to see, it was what you have originally saved, my issue: http://openradar.io/18549283 btw do you have any progress since then?

Comment: @János I have created issue on bugreport.apple.com, once Apple asked for my iCloud logs - I sent logs. Now I am waiting for fixing it :)

Comment: you could report your issue after  bugreport on `openradar` too, then outsiders like me could read it too

Comment: get logs you mean `println("\(error.localizedDescription)")`? or is it any other way to investigate how iCloud works?

Comment: there is so few experts to ask and especially `CKSubscription` is kind of a buggy, hard to move on

Comment: @János I installed special provisioning profile, play my error and exported iCloud logs from iOS. Apple sent me provisioning profile, instruction and notice about NDA :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62483/discussion-between-k06a-and-janos).

Comment: Check this one too http://openradar.appspot.com/18807663, oh and this one http://openradar.appspot.com/18798061 . I've already cursed the CloudKit. The predicates are such undocumented and restricted in compare to core data ones.

Comment: I confirm that CKSubscription doesnt work with compound predicates in some cases.

Comment: @k06a can you update your question adding some recently mentioned radars here in comments section?

Comment: @purrrminator I'll add mention and some workaround

Comment: my compound predicate start to working after I changed the format from this `field1 == %@ && field2 == %@` to `(field1 == %@) AND (field2 == %@)`

Comment: Maybe your predicate will work like this `@"((value > %@) AND (prev_value < %@)) AND (event_type IN %@)"`

Comment: Arrrggh. My predicate only working with `FiresOnRecordUpdate` option. Not working  with `FiresOnRecordDeletion`. Damn!

Comment: ^ fixed with this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822019/observe-ckrecord-deletion-via-cksubscription-does-not-work

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a CKNotification object, add it to the subscription before you add the subscription to the database. Also make sure you inspect all of the delegate methods related to the remote notification including the didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError. Regarding the predicate issue, I'd recommend trying out [NSCompoundPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCompoundPredicate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSCompoundPredicate) and a deeper review of the [Predicates Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789) for other options.