# Observe CKRecord deletion via CKSubscription does not work

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios8, cloudkit, cksubscription

`CKSubscription` doc says: *When a record modification causes a subscription to fire, the server sends push notifications to all devices with that subscription **except for the one that made the original change** to the record.*

Let assume I have two devices: `device 1` and `device 2` logged in from different iCloud accounts. Let assume both devices subscribed for record deletion for a certain record type.

1. If  `device 1` creates a record and then `device 1` deletes it then `device 2` get notified - THAT IS ACCORDING TO THE DOC, BUT ..
2. If `device 1` creates a record and then `device 2` deletes it then `device 2` get notified - I do NOT think it is ACCORDING TO THE DOC, and IT DOES NOT MAKE ANY SENSE, **`device 2` deleted it so `device 1` should be notified**

---

**SET UP SUBSCRIPTION ON DEVICE 1 AND DEVICE 2**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert, categories: nil))
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    let defaultContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let publicDatabase = defaultContainer.publicCloudDatabase

    publicDatabase.fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletionHandler({subscriptions, error in

        if error == nil {

            if subscriptions.count == 0 {

                let subscription = CKSubscription(recordType: "OU", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: .FiresOnRecordDeletion)
                subscription.notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
                subscription.notificationInfo.shouldBadge = false
                subscription.notificationInfo.alertBody = "OU removed or upated"
                publicDatabase.saveSubscription(subscription, completionHandler: {subscription, error in
                    if error == nil {
                    } else {
                        println("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                })
            }

        } else {
            println("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })


    return true
}
```

---

**CREATE RECORD on DEVICE 1**

```
@IBAction func addOU(sender: AnyObject) {

    var defaultContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    var publicDatabase = defaultContainer.publicCloudDatabase

    let r = CKRecord(recordType: "OU", recordID: CKRecordID(recordName: "aaaa"))
    publicDatabase.saveRecord(r, completionHandler: { r2, error in

        if error == nil {
        } else {
            println("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
}
```

---

**DELETE RECORD ON DEVICE 2**

```
@IBAction func removeOU(sender: AnyObject) {

    var defaultContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    var publicDatabase = defaultContainer.publicCloudDatabase

    publicDatabase.deleteRecordWithID(CKRecordID(recordName: "aaaa"), completionHandler: {recordID, error in

        if error == nil {

        } else {
            println("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I've radared the bug  rdar://18810914

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I still think that IT MAKE NO SENSE how `CKSubscription` works, but as a temporary fix I recommend to changed first `CKRecord`'s `lastModifiedUserRecordID` to the user who want to delete the record, and only afterwards to delete record.

To change `lastModifiedUserRecordID` you have to **fetch it and without do anything on it save it back**, and then deletion can come:

```
@IBAction func removeOU(sender: AnyObject) {

    var defaultContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    var publicDatabase = defaultContainer.publicCloudDatabase

    publicDatabase.fetchRecordWithID(CKRecordID(recordName: "aaaa"), completionHandler: {record, error in

        if error == nil {

            publicDatabase.saveRecord(record, completionHandler: {record2, error in

                if error == nil {

                    publicDatabase.deleteRecordWithID(CKRecordID(recordName: "aaaa"), completionHandler: {recordID, error in

                        if error == nil {

                        } else {
                            println("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    println("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            })

        } else {
            println("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: oh my god... Does this bug was reported? Radar?

Comment: got familiar trouble and your workaround helped me. In my case was following problem: Device 1 created a record and subscribed for the record gets deleted. Device 2 deleted the record. Device 1 not get notified.

Comment: me too rdar://18810914

Comment: I have reported 3 issues regarding `CKSubscription` :-(

Comment: this is insane. caused me 3 weeks of troubleshooting my offline-sync feature.

Comment: i just tried it, doesn't work for private databases.

Comment: There are public databases and private databases in `CloudKit`. Private databases are user specific data that other users cannot see.

Comment: I spent hours just to find out that the subscriptions was broken last days. The workaround had been working for me for some time a month ago, but now it doesn't. @Ninja why do you think the subscriptions must work in private db? Have you ever wanted a push notification that notifys you about the action you just done? I don't think so.

Comment: @János I even tried to add bool attribute to my Record Type and change it's value before re-save the record back. Doesn't helps. Can you say something? Does your solution still works for you?

Comment: @purrrminator there is one use case, for example: to ping other devices to sync new data from a private database.

Comment: @Ninja I got it, good one. Have you tried zone subscriptions? I think they should work without the workaround, described here. Not sure if they are able to filter out particular record's changes though.

Comment: I've just received an answer to the bugreport, I created according to this  question. They said that it is fixed now. Can anyone approve this? Will check this later right on my app.

Comment: I've just checked the bugfix. It is fixed indeed. Hooray!