# CloudKit subscriptions only works for dashboard operations

Tags: notifications, push-notification, cloudkit, cksubscription

My subscription is based on a simple predicate

```
NSPredicate * sPredicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(inviteCode == %@)", walletUser.inviteCode];
CKSubscription * s = [[CKSubscription alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Invite"
                                                          predicate:sPredicate1
                                                     subscriptionID:sID 
                              options:CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordDeletion];
```

It simply observing one record with specific inviteCode and fire a notification when the record is deleted (the invite was accepted by other user).
However it does not firing any push notifications in case I remove the Invite programmatically from other device. But it does send me a notification when I remove the Invite from the Dashboard. Can someone help me with this bug?

PS. I'm pretty sure that the subscription is succesfully saved on server - I see it on dashboard.

**UPDATED:**

The answer was given here
[Observe CKRecord deletion via CKSubscription does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822019/observe-ckrecord-deletion-via-cksubscription-does-not-work)

Comment: Also, notifications only work on actual devices, not the simulator.