# CloudKit subscription only works when operation is performed in CloudKit Dashboard and not when done programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, cloudkit

I have set up a `CKQuerySubscription` in the default zone that sends a Push notification every time a record meeting the given criteria is deleted in a public CloudKit database. However, the notification is only sent when I delete the record via the CloudKit Dashboard and not when I delete a record programmatically.

This question is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632097/cloudkit-subscriptions-only-works-for-dashboard-operations) however it's almost 10 years old and the linked solution of saving the record before deleting does not work.

I have tried creating a record with User A on a device and then having that record deleted by User B on a different device but it doesn't result in User A getting notified.

Additionally, the only case where the notification gets sent is on a device that is signed in with the iCloud account that I use for CloudKit Console. In other words, when I delete a record that was created by a user with a different iCloud account than the one I use for the CloudKit Console the notification does not get sent to that device - it's only successful on the device with the CloudKit Console iCloud account.

What I expect to happen is the subscription to fire when the record in question is deleted regardless of how and by whom it is deleted. Is this possible?

**Update**: *Any* operation that I perform programmatically on the public CloudKit database (creating a record, deleting a record) is not triggering the subscription I set up to fire, even when the subscription's predicate is set to `NSPredicate(value: true)`. The subscription only fires when I perform these operations manually on the CloudKit Dashboard. It seems that I need to find a way to replicate the actions that take place when I perform operations on the Dashboard in my code...

Any help would be appreciated.